# Postgres SELECT rows plus the next row with criteria

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I wonder if someone could give me some hints.

I have a simple query which selects rows based on a normal criteria:

```
SELECT ntl.id,ntl.transaction_date, amount
FROM nominal_transaction_lines ntl
WHERE ntl.courier_information = 468323802;
```

What I want to get is not only these rows but also the next row if the next row 
has a specific criteria.

For example

```
SELECT ntl.id,ntl.transaction_date, amount
FROM nominal_transaction_lines ntl
WHERE ntl.description = 'fue@'
AND id = (values of id from first select)+1;
```

The final `rowset` would be the `union` of both results.

Could this be done as a `cte`?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Something likes this?WITH tmp AS (SELECT * FROM nominal_transaction_lines WHERE courier_information = 468323802 ) SELECT * FROM tmp t UNION SELECT * FROM nominal_transaction_lines WHERE id = tmp.id + 1;

Comment: I haven't tryied that yet, but this should work: WITH tmp AS (SELECT *
FROM nominal_transaction_lines
WHERE courier_information = 468323802
)
SELECT *
FROM tmp t
UNION
SELECT *
FROM nominal_transaction_lines ntl
JOIN tmp t ON t.id + 1= ntl.id;

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My answer must have crossed with your reply. I think your solution might be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can accept getting the data you want merged into the same rows, this could be a simple join.

```
SELECT ntl.id, ntl.transaction_date, ntl.amount, ntl_next.id, ntl_next.transaction_date, ntl_next.amount
FROM nominal_transaction_lines ntl
LEFT OUTER JOIN nominal_transaction_lines ntl_next ON ntl_next.id = ntl.id + 1
WHERE ntl.courier_information = 468323802;
```

If you need them to be separate rows, but in the same result set, you can use a CTE

```
WITH base AS (
    SELECT ntl.id, ntl.transaction_date, amount
    FROM nominal_transaction_lines ntl
    WHERE ntl.courier_information = 468323802
)
SELECT b.id, b.transaction_date, b.amount
FROM base b

UNION

SELECT ntl_next.id, ntl_next.transaction_date, ntl_next.amount
FROM base b
INNER JOIN nominal_transaction_lines ntl_next on ntl_next.id = b.id + 1;
```

I would recommend the first approach if it meets your needs because it is much simpler.

Comment: I like the first approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I rushed to ask the question, but then worked it out.

It can be done as a `CTE`:

```
WITH 
ntl1 AS(
SELECT ntl.id AS thisrow, ntl.id+1 AS nextrow
FROM nominal_transaction_lines ntl
WHERE ntl.courier_information = 468323802),

ntl2 AS(
SELECT ntl.id,amount
FROM nominal_transaction_lines ntl
JOIN ntl1 ON ntl1.thisrow = ntl.id),

ntl3 AS(
SELECT ntl.id,amount
FROM nominal_transaction_lines ntl
JOIN ntl1 ON ntl1.nextrow = ntl.id
WHERE ntl.line_description LIKE 'Fuel%')

SELECT * FROM ntl2
UNION
SELECT * FROM ntl3;
```

Of course if anyone has better ideas I would be happy to hear them.